# How to configure a ClusterRole for namespaced resources

Tags: kubernetes, roles, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-cluster-role

I want to allow a ServiceAccount in namespace A to access a resource in namespace B.
To achieve this I connect the ServiceAccount to a ClusterRole via a ClusterRoleBinding.
[The documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) says I can "use a ClusterRole to [1.] define permissions on namespaced resources and be granted within individual namespace(s)"

But looking through the [K8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#policyrule-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io) I can't find a way how to create a ClusterRole with namespaced resources. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm newish to k8s but I think the version of the docs you've cited may be misleading. @damick's answer below about using RoleBinding instead of ClusterRoleBinding seems to get us most of the way to our answer. With a ClusterRole, you can define a resource name e.g., 'foo'. By using a (non-Cluster) RoleBinding for each of namespaces a, b and c; you can grant access to the a:foo, b:foo and c:foo resources. I don't think we can specify fully-qualified resources from the ClusterRole. To grant different resource names in each namespace, I think we need a Role and RoleBinding for each namespace.

Answer (score 4):

I find both other answers a little confusing, hopefully this is clearer.

You did the right thing in creating a `ClusterRole`, but you want to bind it using a namespaced `RoleBinding`, *not* a `ClusterRoleBinding`.

Example using your examples. Notice how the `RoleBinding` is in the B namespace, giving A's `ServiceAccount` the permissions defined in the `ClusterRole`, but limited to the B namespace.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: what-a-is-allowed-to-do-in-b
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "deployments"] # etc
  verbs: ["get", "list", "create"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: namespace-a
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: what-a-is-allowed-to-do-in-b
  namespace: namespace-b
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: what-a-is-allowed-to-do-in-b
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-app
  namespace: namespace-a
```

Notes:
You have to use the ClusterRole because you can't get outside your own namespace without one. By using a `RoleBinding`, which is namespaced, you can then limit the access to the scope of the namespace of that `RoleBinding`.

Answer (score 2):

`...how to create a ClusterRole with namespaced resources...`

Read further [down](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrole-example) a bit:

> A ClusterRole can be used to grant the same permissions as a Role.
> Because ClusterRoles are cluster-scoped. You can also use them to
> grant access to:
>
> ...
>
> - namespaced resources (like Pods), **across all namespaces**

`ClusterRole` won't help you to restraint access to a single namespaced object. You can however use `RoleBinding` to reference a `ClusterRole` and restraint access to the object in the namespace of the RoleBinding.

Comment: I see, so what I try to achieve is not possible. I can't define resources in particular namespaces, but roles.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if understood your question correctly you are there already. Just use `RoleBinding` to control resources specified in the `ClusterRole` in the namespace specified by RoleBinding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create clusterrole not role.
example:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: role-grantor
rules:
- apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["rolebindings"]
  verbs: ["create"]
- apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["clusterroles"]
  verbs: ["bind"]
  # omit resourceNames to allow binding any ClusterRole
  resourceNames: ["admin","edit","view"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-grantor-binding
  namespace: user-1-namespace
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: role-grantor
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: user-1
```

above example is from this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#restrictions-on-role-binding-creation-or-update).